# Node.js Error: Cannot find module 'bval' in chainpoint-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, node-modules

So im trying to run my own bitcoin header node. I have been able to sync it but it seems something keeps going wrong. I have tried reinstalling this 'module' a few times and nothing seems to fix it. Im using it with a program called chainpoint-cli which allows me to submit, verify, update proofs but everytime i try running 'chp bhn <command ' it errors out, and when I try 'chp bhn' it says missing module bval but I can see it in the node modules. Was wondering if anyone has any information on a way to fix this.

This is some of the error

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1134
const err = new Error(message);
^

Error: Cannot find module 'bval'
Require stack:

- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chainpoint-cli/node_modules/bhn/lib/http.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chainpoint-cli/node_modules/bhn/lib/headernode.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chainpoint-cli/node_modules/bhn/lib/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chainpoint-cli/lib/bhn/start.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chainpoint-cli/node_modules/yargs/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chainpoint-cli/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chainpoint-cli/chp.js

Comment: Well `bhn` is requiring `bval`, but interestingly `bval` is not a dependency of `bhn`, not even a  peer dependency, so it looks like the repository is broken.   It's not been updated for over 4 years.  But if you want to try and get it to install, you could try manually.  Go to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chainpoint-cli/node_modules/bhn` directory and type `npm install bval`.

Comment: Another idea,  you could try using `yarn` to install instead of `npm`, there is a `yarn.lock` file.   Don't use `yarn` but I've a feeling this `yarn.lock` file will install the dependencies correctly for you.

Comment: For yarn download you might want the classic too, just in case v2 is not compatible. -> https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/

Comment: I've tried that for some reason it says it installs it, but when i try running the command again it just says missing module

Comment: Did you try yarn?

Comment: yeahm just nothing seems to work, its weird cause the node is running. but when i try submitting with Chainpoint i get the error ' | Unable to submit at this time, try again'

Comment: I have noticed tho, when I try to submit i get this error as well: 

request to https://18.191.50.129/hashes failed, reason: write EPROTO 00E8E89D1D7F0000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 80

995a196fac2edef83f1f5b53a3ac2eb1e53253e48ab0b5004082c81f66575d53 | Unable to submit at this time, try again

Comment: I had to download the missing module via 'npm' : 'npm install bval'. Then moving that new module to the modules folder of 'bhn'. This then allowed bhn to run.